# Execute a function on specific page loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run a function only and only when I'm on a specific part of my website and once I leave that part of the website I want to go out of that function. I've tried to do so with

```
window.onload = carousel();
```

But this will happen once the any page of the website loads and not the specific one I want to (`page3.html`).

Only using html, css and javascript. No external libraries and such

Comment: why dont you just put that line of code in `page3.html`?

Comment: hm I suppose that works. But I though it was a good habbit to have a javascript code in a seperate file.

Comment: so have a separate js file, just for page3.html and put it there. I dont follow what the issue is?!?

Comment: Jamiec is correct

Comment: Oh ye I can use multiple javascript files, Sorry I forgot that. I'm pretty new to webbdevelopment

Answer (score 3):

Check the url by using `window.location`. Then wrap that inside a function and assign it to your `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('page3.html') > -1) {
    carousel();
  }
}
```